# Program does not ask for gender although it asks for everything else

Tags: java

Can someone tell me why my program does not ask for gender when I run it although it asks for everything else?

```
import java.util.*;

public class registration {


    public static void main (String[] args) {
     Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter first name");
    String firstName=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Enter surname");
    String surname=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Enter address");
    String address=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Enter age");
    int age=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println ("Enter gender");
    String gender=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Enter telephone contact");
    String teleContact=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Enter P for Platinum, G for Gold or S for Silver membership type");
    String memberType=in.nextLine();
    int birth;
    birth=2014-age;
    String surname2;
    surname2 = surname.toUpperCase();
    String memberId;
    memberId=memberType + surname2 + birth;
    System.out.printf ("MEMBER ID : " + memberId + "   ");
    System.out.printf ("FIRSTNAME : " + surname + "   ");
    System.out.printf ("SURNAME : " + firstName + "   ");
    System.out.printf ("AGE : " + age + "   ");
    System.out.printf ("GENDER : " + gender + "   ");
    System.out.printf ("TELEPHONE : " + teleContact + "   ");
    System.out.printf ("MEMBERSHIP TYPE : " + memberType + "   ");
    System.out.printf ("ADDRESS : " + address + "   ");


    }


}
```

Comment: Do you provide a valid age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextInt() is not consuming the new line character you are entering, so it is then  consumed by the following in.nextLine(), and therefore you don't get the chance to enter the gender.

I suggest you change the nextInt for nextLine() and then call Integer.parseInt() on that line, catching the necessary exception, in case the line is not a valid number.

Answer (score 1):

```
int age=in.nextInt();
```

Is only consuming the "int" part.

The

```
 String gender=in.nextLine();
```

Consumes the (empty) newline and moves on.

You need to consume both before you prompt for Gender.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nextInt() doesn't expect a newline, so the input is stalled pending a newline.  Change the nextInt() to nextLine() and parse the int, and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

put `in.nextLine()` after  System.out.println ("Enter gender"); line.Because after integer it takes newline as string therefore it just skip by pressing "enter".